# Excel VBA - Footer doesn't update correctly through the code

Tags: excel, vba

I have come across a strange behavior while writing code to update custom number in footer through VBA. I am using Excel 365.

Objective: To write custom page numbers to each sheet.

I have written below code which works to an extent.

```
Sub TestHdrFooter()
Dim wksCurr As Worksheet
Dim lngPageBase As Long, lngShtLen As Long
Dim strBaseDocNumb As String, strRev As String, strExpr As String

lngPageBase = 2
strBaseDocNumb = "DOC-99-100000-AA-9999-99999"
strRev = "01"
lngShtLen = Len("0005")

For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Set wksCurr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
    With wksCurr.PageSetup
        '\\ Reset footer if something has been accidentally entered
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        
        If Len(CStr(lngPageBase)) = 1 Then
            .RightFooter = strBaseDocNumb & "-" & Application.Rept("0", lngShtLen - 1) & " &[Page]+" & lngPageBase & "-" & strRev
        Else
            .RightFooter = strBaseDocNumb & "-" & Application.Rept("0", lngShtLen - 2) & " &[Page]+" & lngPageBase & "-" & strRev
        End If
        
        lngPageBase = lngPageBase + .Pages.Count
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

However, it doesn't update correctly directly as when I open it through `Page Setup>>Header/Footer` I see it appears as below without the opening bracket which is available in the code.

[image]

Then comes the stranger part. When I open the "custom Footer" dialog on the form, it shows the missing bracket and then simply pressing "OK" when closing this dialog updates everything correctly without having to change anything! I am not able to guess the reason for this behavior.

[image]

Questions:

1. Is there anything wrong with my VBA code that needs to be amended?
2. Is there any way to force refreshing the expression that appears in second screenshoot if code is correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I should've read Microsoft's documentation before posting the question. My code expression while it appears correct literally, it isn't the proper way to use it through VBA.

Incorrect expression:

`.RightFooter = strBaseDocNumb & "-" & Application.Rept("0", lngShtLen - 1) & " &[Page]+" & lngPageBase & "-" & strRev`

Correct expression:

`.RightFooter = strBaseDocNumb & "-" & Application.Rept("0", lngShtLen - 1) & "&P+" & lngPageBase & "-" & strRev`

Notice the change in Page part. This is clearly mentioned in MS Documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb225426(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN